# order hierarchy from types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to convert between types in both directions

Is it possible to create an order hierarchy from types as in an Enum?

```
data Longitud a = Pies Float | Pulgadas Float | Yardas Float | Cm Float | Metros Float deriving (Show)

--toYardas:: Longitud a -> Longitud a
toYardas (Pies x) = Yardas $ x/3
toYardas x = toYardas $ toPies x

toPies (Pulgadas x) = Pies $ x/12
toPies (Yardas x) = Pies $ x*3
toPies x = toPies $ toYardas x --if bigger type
toPies x = toPies $ toPulgadas x --if smaller type

toPulgadas (Cm x) = Pulgadas $ x/2.54
toPulgadas (Pies x) = Pulgadas $ x*12

toCm (Pulgadas x) = Cm $ x*2.54
toCm (Metros x) = Cm $ x*100

toMetros (Cm x) = Metros $ x/100
```

**Edit**: What I am looking for is a way to compare if Cm>Metros or Cm<Metros in a hierarchy of types, not about comparing their contents, that's why I don't think deriving Ord would help.

Comment: You can certainly define an ordering on this type.  Is that all you want, to make this an `Ord` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to talk about the units themselves as first-class values, not just constructors holding numbers, and because you want to store them uniformly, I suggest refactoring your type to hold the unit and the value in two separate fields:

```
data Unit = Pies | Pulgada | ... deriving Ord

data Longitud = Longitud Unit Float
```

Then you can easily compare units, since they are separate from their values:

```
toPies old@(Longitud unit amt) = case unit of
  Pies -> old
  Pulgadas -> Longitud Pies $ amt / 12
  Yardas -> Longitud Pies $ amt * 3
  u | u > Yardas -> toPies $ toYardas old
    | u < Pulgadas -> toPies $ toPulgadas old
    | otherwise = error "unknown unit"
```

I do agree with Louis that if you just tack an Ord instance onto your type, it should work as you want for this case. But it doesn't really feel right to me to compare two Longitud values when all you really care about is what constructor they have, and never expect their magnitudes to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

`deriving (Ord)` actually ought to do exactly what you want, including the type constructors.  From [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html):

> The class methods automatically introduced by derived instances of Eq and Ord are (==), (/=), compare, (<), (<=), (>), (>=), max, and min. The latter seven operators are defined so as to compare their arguments lexicographically with respect to the constructor set given, with earlier constructors in the datatype declaration counting as smaller than later ones.